# Change name of generated PDB file to include .exe or .dll extension of its executable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, pdb-files

In Visual Studio 2010, is it possible to change the naming of the .pdb file to include the full name of the executable, including its extension, and that debugging will still work?

For example, suppose I have an executable `myprogram.exe`, I want the pdb to be `myprogram.exe.pdb` rather than `myprogram.pdb`. Similarly, I want `mylibrary.dll` to have `mylibrary.dll.pdb` rather than `mylibrary.pdb`.

Comment: My apologies for not saying - C#

Lee

Answer (score 1):

`.pdb` name is specified in `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets` file.

```
<_DebugSymbolsIntermediatePath Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetName).pdb" Condition="'$(_DebugSymbolsProduced)'=='true' and '@(_DebugSymbolsIntermediatePath)'==''"/>
```

You can edit it to override `.pdb` file names globally.

Comment: Or you can specify 

<PropertyGroup><PdbFile>ABC</PdbFile></PropertyGroup>

to give the PDB file a different name. Note that I am not aware of a way to change the file extension. If you supply a different file extension to csc.exe, then the compiler will change your file extension to .pdb